# Can G, H, and S be negative?

Tags: thermodynamics

1. Consider Gibb's free energy of a reaction in a closed system $G = H - TS$. Can $G$ ever be negative? (note, I am not talking about $\Delta G$)

I would suspect no because there is always some energy on every system.

2. What about $H$ and $S$? Are they nonnegative?

I would suspect yes because if there are bonds then they have internal PE and KE. I wouldn't know how to interpret negative disorder.

3. Is $H \ge TS$ always?

Variation on 1)

Comment: Are you asking about absolute values, values relative to some reference state, or changes in these functions?

Comment: Asking about absolute "measured" values and not changes. I am trying to understand them and interpret them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

G and H are like altitude.  They are not absolute; rather their values are always relative to whatever you set as a reference. So they can be either positive or negative.  There is no general constraint on the sign of their values.  For this reason, we usually talk about $\Delta G$ or $\Delta H$, since it's the changes that are meaningful; giving them arbitrary values isn't typically useful.

By contrast, there is a non-arbitrary zero for entropy.  In classical thermodynamics, it's the entropy of a pure substance at absolute zero. Since the temperature can never be lower than absolute zero in a system at thermodynamic equilibrium, $S$ (as opposed to $\Delta S$) can never be negative.

In statistical mechanics, there are various equivalent ways of defining the entropy, depending on the ensemble you are using.  The simplest definition is that for the microcanonical ensemble:

$$S = k_B \ln \Omega,$$

where $\Omega$ is the number of possible microstates of the system, and $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant.  Since the minimum number of microstates is 1 (which happens at absolute zero), the minimum value for $S$ is zero.

Comment: If $H = U + pV$ where pressure $p \ge 0$ and $V \ge 0$, could internal energy $U$ be negative? Is there any way of computing it (i.e. wrt some reference) that allows it to be negative? I am curious if you can provide an example... I am especially curious about how to interpret it if it were negative.

Comment: @SeanRoody (1) Sure, $U$ can be negative. After all, you can define your reference for enthalpy such that $H<0$.  And if $H<0$, and $pV>0$, then it must be the case that $U<0$.

Comment: (2)There is no special significance to $U$ being negative; whether it's negative or positive depends on what you've set as your zero. E.g., suppose you want to measure all altitudes relative to Denver, CO (1600 m above sea level). Then the altitude at sea level becomes –1600 m. Is there any special signficance to the altitude at sea level now being –1600 m? Does it change anything about the physical properties of the atmosphere at sea level if you use this new system? Does it change how high you actually are if you use this new system? Answers: no and no. All you've done is to reset your zero.

Comment: As a specific example for OP: potential energy of electron/nucleus interactions is usually defined with respect to 0 being the state where electron and nucleus are infinitely far apart. Thus PE for an electron bound to a nucleus is always negative. The choice of 0 is arbitrary.

Comment: One could get somewhat philosophical and say that there is an absolute zero of energy, namely the absence thereof (say, at 0 K). Would that be an "arbitrary definition"?

Comment: @BuckThorn  It's an interesting thought but, at $0$ K, you would still have PE based on the pressure, so that would need to be specified also ($p=0$?).  Of course, even if you selected a pressure, you'd still have mass-energy which, IIUC, is based on the invariant mass (which used to be called the rest mass).  There's the KE of the sys. as a whole, but that's explicitly ignored in calculating int. energy. But there's also the energy from the expansion or  contraction of space-time (see http://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2010/02/22/energy-is-not-conserved/ ); is that part of $U$?